# Invalid Python interpreter selected for the project

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, python-venv

I use Pycharm, and whenever I move a project to another folder, it says "invalid python interpreter selected for the project". I think it happens because the path to venv has changed.

I tried Configure Python Interpreter > Add Interpreter > Select "Existing Environment" with the new path to venv. I was expecting this to work, but after I click OK, it says "Updating interpreter path" for a moment, and nothing changes. I tried even checking "make available to all projects".

I also tried some of stack overflow answers, but couldn't make it. How can I fix this?

```
Error:Cannot run program "C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\Digital Clock\venv\Scripts\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\60 Python Projects\Digital Clock"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtualenv has hardcoded path inside the `bin/activate` file, which will fail when you move the virtualenv.

One way is to recreate your virtualenv. Another way is to open the file `bin/activate` and find this line `VIRTUAL_ENV='/private/tmp/test2/.venv'` and replace it with your new virtualenv path.

My virtualenv is created at `/tmp/test2/.venv` for reference.

Comment: Where do I find those files, and Do I get same error if I shift to Conda Environment!

Comment: Based on your error message, your virtualenv is here. `C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\Digital Clock\venv`. So open that directory, and inside `bin/` folder, you will see `activate` file.

Comment: Can you list down which is your old path, and which is your new path in your question?

Comment: This is my old path `VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\Digital Clock\venv"` and following one is new `VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\60 Python Projects\Digital Clock\venv"`

Comment: It looks like your error is from your old path. Python cannot find `can't open file 'C:\Users\aksha\Pycharm\Digital Clock\digitalClock.py'` this file. So this probably has to do with the way you are executing your python file.

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to re-import your project to pycharm, and create a new virtualenv.

Comment: For me, nothing worked. Even after I deleted the existing venv and created a new venv, I wasn't able to select the new interpreter for the project. So, I ended up with creating a new project in the same location of the existing project. It kind of refreshed the existing project I guess. I created a new venv and will install everything from scratch. If you do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` before deleting the old venv, now you can simply do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install everything you previously had.

Comment: This worked for me, seems like this issue is still present in 2023. The funny thing is, in selecting the interpreter it shows the correct path to the binary, but it does not transfer that path to the 'activate' file.

Answer (score 2):

@thuyein's answer did work for me. However, you can also find references to VIRTUAL_ENV in: activate.bat, activate.fish, activate.nu. I updated all of those, then updated the path to interpreter in interpreter's settings as well.

In *settings/Project:[your_project_name]/Python Interpreter* the gear icon next to Python Interpreter's path contains 'Show all' option. These are all interpreters that Pycharm found on your machine. The paths that got messed up are highlighted in red and marked as [Invalid]. Choose the original path of your project's interpreter and just update it (there's an Edit button at the top of the list) - then you'll be able to set it as current interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are as follows.

1. Open Pycharm
2. On extrem right bottom, click on Python version (for example 3.11)
3. Select Interpreter Settings
4. A new window will popup where select the project (project:YOUR_PROJECT_NAME)
5. From right hand side window select python.exe and click on Ok

it should resolve this issue, I've just sorted out following these steps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, PyCharm did not have permissions to read `/usr/local` due to its confinement. I uninstalled it, then installed it as:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
```

This gave it the required permissions, following which the interpreter error did not reoccur. Following this, [create a launcher entry](https://askubuntu.com/a/1454781/) for it.

For `flatpak`, consider [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094903/).

Answer (score 0):

python interpreter re-link to new py3 install/update

Go to programs on Windows menu, find go to letter P section and find your python3 folder 
and right-click on your python3 to get the path copy,
 next open > in new window > do this until you get to the full path way to the python3 execute file in the python folder, not the shortcut link folder.

Copy your full path by right-click on python exe and copy path.
 Next you will go to the pyCharm > settings > python interpreter > then you will click on existing interpreter option
 click on the address bar in the pop box, until you can enter your own address in the top search area, paste your fullpath address to the python exe file in the box and it should populate w/ the file tree showing your execute file.  Save.  Once you re-install your interpreter you should see your packages on the bottom tab refill.