# Unable to add virtual environment Python interpreter to Pycharm project after changing the path

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, interpreter

My issue seems to be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222454/invalid-python-interpreter-selected-for-the-project), but it's for an older Pycharm version (I am on 2023.3.3), and none of the solutions have worked, so I hope it's okay to post a new question.

After moving a project to a different folder, the Python interpreter was, as expected, shown as invalid. The interpreter settings window looks like this:
[Interpreter settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6kPt.png)

Adding an existing interpreter, with the correct new path to python.exe inside the venv folder changes nothing in the interpreter settings window. I still get some progress bars on updating some stuff in the bottom right, but nothing seems to be different afterwards.

Renaming the old venv folder and creating a new environment does create a new venv folder with an activate file pointing to the correct path, but the settings window shown in the image still has no new options. Adding an existing environment with the new path after this still does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried running `File > Invalidate Caches` yet? Could be bad local state in the IDE

Comment: @flakes Tried that now, and it didn't help unfortunately